# Значение фразы «замочу тебя я прямо в упор»

Tags: фразеология, значение-слов

Я пытаюсь точно понять текст популярной песни. И у меня проблема с такой фразой: «замочу тебя я прямо в упор». На форуме нашел объяснение значения «замочить кого-то» на сленге как «убить», возможно ножом. «Прямо в упор» я так понимаю - «в цель, в точку». Но всё это вместе для меня значимого целого не составляет - но я иностранец.
Тупик. «Я ударю тебя ножом в сердце» - возможно ли это так объяснять?

Answer (score 1):

> «Прямо в упор» я так понимаю - «в цель, в точку»

Нет, совершенно другой смысл. "Прямо в упор" = "вплотную", "упираясь в тебя", "на близком расстоянии", "лицом к лицу".

> «Я ударю тебя ножом в сердце» - возможно ли это так объяснять?

Нет, здесь совершенно другая синтаксическая структура. "в сердце" - здесь дополнение (вопрос: ударю во что? - в сердце).

> «Замочу тебя я прямо в упор»

Здесь "прямо" - усилительная частица, и может быть опущено без потери структуры и смысла.

> «Замочу тебя в упор»

Здесь "в упор" наречное выражение, отвечающее на вопрос (как?).
Его можно заменить на "вплотную" (хотя так не принято говорить)

Точный смысл такой

> «Я застрелю тебя, уперев пистолет в твое тело»

"Убить ножом в упор" - так не говорят, потому что это тавтология.

Comment: Теперь я точно вижу, что у меня не было никаких шансов :( Если вы знаете язык только со школы, часто бывает очень трудно понять тексты современных песен. Большое спасибо за вашу помощь.